# Search for a phrase and a word together in one sentence using Lucene

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am working on a program that will search two keywords in a sentence using Apache Lucene. For example

keyword1 = "Green Apple";
keyword2 = "Orange";
Both of the keywords Must be there in a sentence.

However, I am able to search "orange" and "apple" so far but not the combination of phrase and word. The sentences and my query are as follows:

> "Sentences: An apple is red. A Green Apple is good. I like Green apple and orange."

I want to  search a sentence where both the keywords exist.

```
    String keyword1 = "Green Apple";
    String keyword2 = "Orange";
    QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "contents",
            new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
    Query query = queryParser.parse("" + keyword1+ " AND" + " " + keyword2);
```

Using this query I am not able to find the sentence. However for `keyword1 = Apple;` and `keyword2 = Orange;` the query works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to surround those "keywords", as you call them, with quotes so that Lucene can construct a phrase query with them. If the parser finds a space it just uses a default operator (OR by default).

So the code should be:

```
Query query = queryParser.parse("\"" + keyword1 + "\" AND" + "\"" + keyword2 + "\"");
```